# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'int'

Tags: python, types

when I run the code below with 3 integer arguments,

```
import sys
import numpy as np

fichier=open("vocLemma.tsv")
dico=dict()

borneMin=int(sys.argv[1])
borneMax=int(sys.argv[2])
nbClasseMax=int(sys.argv[3])
cpt=0

error=0
for ligne in fichier:
    try:
        tab=ligne.split("\t")
        mot=tab[0]
        freq=map(int, list(tab[1].strip("[").strip("]").replace(" ", "").split(",")))
        nbAnnee=int(tab[2])
        classes=tab[3]
        nbClasse=0
        for classe in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]:
            if classe in classes:
                nbClasse+=1
        docTotal=np.sum(np.array(freq))
        if not mot.isdigit() and nbAnnee > 1 and docTotal > borneMin and docTotal < borneMax and nbClasse <= nbClasseMax:
            dico[tab[0].strip()]=ligne.strip()
            cpt+=1
    except IndexError:
        error+=1
        pass
print(cpt)
fichier =open("voc_freqmin"+str(borneMin)+"_docmax"+str(borneMax)+"_classemax"+str(nbClasseMax), "w")
for mot in dico:
    fichier.write(dico[mot]+"\n")
fichier.close()
```

I get an error message like :

```
File "filtre.py", line 25, in <module>
    if not mot.isdigit() and nbAnnee > 1 and docTotal > borneMin and docTotal < borneMax and nbClasse <= nbClasseMax:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'int'
```

but I don't know why. Does anyone can help me? Thanks!

---

Solved. And I add this note from @randomfigure , "this is a common error people encounter when porting from python2 to python3" (saying, use of 'map')

Comment: could you print the values of `nbAnnee ,  docTotal, borneMin` in line 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function returns a `map` object, not a list.  In this line:

```
freq=map(int, list(tab[1].strip("[").strip("]").replace(" ", "").split(",")))
```

you define `freq` to be a `map` object.  Later, when you pass it through numpy operations, it is still just an array of a single `map` object.  This line:

```
docTotal=np.sum(np.array(freq))
```

Does not return an number, but rather another `map` object.

You can fix this using:

```
freq=list(map(int, list(tab[1].strip("[").strip("]").replace(" ", "").split(","))))
```

Comment: I think it would be worth it to note this is a common error people encounter when porting from python2 to python3

Comment: Thank you James, it fixed the error! And I agree with @randomfigure , this code seems to originally be written in python2